# How does the expression r[[2,3],[2,3]] access an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I am new to Python and I am learning from an online course. In a quiz, I was asked this question:

[The choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rqhB.jpg)

I have correctly solved it, but I was looking at the other choices wondering how they would select indices in an array and I have understood all but the 2nd choice:

```
r[[2,3],[2,3]]
```

I tried searching for it online but I haven't found an example like it. Is this correct Python syntax? And if so, how would it access an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , it will return `r[2,2]` and `r[3,3]` as answer.

In this syntax, first list will correspond to the row coordinates and the second list will correspond to its respective col coordinates.

For eg:

```
r = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]])
print(r[[2,3],[2,3]])
```

output will be

`array([11, 16])`

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried it before asking but couldn't understand how the output was retrieved or if there was any logic behind it. I do now!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is probably incorrect. The list index must be integer, not tuple